# Maven eclipse project dependencies

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have set up Eclipse Helios with Maven 2 Integration. Now I have two projects which point to the same repository. 
One requires the other, but since Maven handles all dependencies I cannot add the project directly to the build path. Instead I defined it as a dependency in pom.xml

Now whenever I call maven assemble on the parent-project I get a class not found exception even though the sub-project built fine. (I updated dependencies)

Another question: Shouldn't there be pre-defined goals? When I create my own maven run configuration there are no goals available. Is my configuration messed up?

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the first problem by running eclipse with JDK 6, pre-defined goals are still missing however. Entering stuff like "compile" manually does work.